# Are pointers private in OpenMP parallel sections?

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I've added OpenMP to an existing code base in order to parallelize a for loop.  Several variables are created inside the scope of the `parallel for` region, including a pointer:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    [....]
    Model *lm;
    lm->myfunc();
    lm->anotherfunc();
    [....]
}
```

In the resulting output files I noticed inconsistencies, presumably caused by a race condition.  I ultimately resolved the race condition by using an `omp critical`.  My question remains, though:  is `lm` private to each thread, or is it shared?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, all variables declared inside the OpenMP region are private. This includes pointers.

Each thread will have its own copy of the pointer.

It lets you do stuff like this:

```
int threads = 8;
int size_per_thread = 10000000;

int *ptr = new int[size_per_thread * threads];

#pragma omp parallel num_threads(threads)
    {
        int id = omp_get_thread_num();
        int *my_ptr = ptr + size_per_thread * id;

        //  Do work on "my_ptr".
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  From reading the spec, it _seemed_ as if that were the case, but it was a bit unclear.