# Use table in parallel program (openmp)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, openmp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are pointers private in OpenMP parallel sections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735332/are-pointers-private-in-openmp-parallel-sections)

I want to use a table in a parallel part in a openmp program.
I cannot declare it in the parallel part, this gives too much overflow, so I declare it in advance try to declare it private.

Original Program:

```
 int i,j;
#pragma omp parallel for private(i,j) 
for(i=startvalueX; i<stopvalueX; i++) { 
   for(j=startvalueY; j<stopvalueY; j++) {  
        int *subimage=new int[9];
   }
}
```

Advance declaration

```
int i,j;
int *subimage;
#pragma omp parallel for private(i,j,subimage) 
for(i=startvalueX; i<stopvalueX; i++) { 
   for(j=startvalueY; j<stopvalueY; j++) {  
        subimage=new int[9];
   }
}
```

As output I get a memory dump. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: found answer at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735332/are-pointers-private-in-openmp-parallel-sections